# SQL IN Operator in DataTable Select method in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is there a function to write this in DataTable Select method in VB.net?

SQL Query that I would like use

```
SELECT id from mytable where id in ('a','b','c')
```

I have this code to create query but it would be nice if I can use IN clause

```
    For Each typeitem In shapecb.Items
        If Stntypeitem.Selected = True Then
            If o = True Then
                sqlfil += " AND Shape = '" + typeitem.Value + "'"
            Else
                sqlfil += "Shape = '" + typeitem.Value + "'"
                o = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Dim bindtable As DataTable = dt.Clone
    Dim rows As DataRow() = dt.[Select](sqlfil)
    For Each row As DataRow In rows
        bindtable.ImportRow(row)
    Next
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LINQ-to-DataSet` to filter your `DataTable`

```
Dim shapes = {"a", "b", "c"}
Dim tbl = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable
          Where shapes.Contains(row.Field(Of String)("Shape"))).CopyToDataTable
```

or in fluent syntax:

```
tbl = dt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(r) shapes.Contains(r.Field(Of String)("Shape"))).CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what type `shapecb` is, therefore you might have to change the type I specified in the cast. (I assumed it was a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`.)

```
Dim strings = _
    From item In shapecb.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() _
    Where item.Selected _
    Select "'" & item.Value & "'"

Dim inList As String = String.Join(",", strings.ToArray())
Dim sql As String = "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (" & inList & ")"
```

---

**EDIT** (in response to comment):

LINQ provides an alternative, often more concise way to do things. The same problem would be solved like this in the traditional way:

```
Dim strings = New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To shapecb.Items.Count - 1
    Dim item As ListItem = shapecb.Items(0)
    If item.Selected Then
        strings.Add("'" & item.Value & "'")
    End If
Next

Dim inList As String = String.Join(",", strings.ToArray())
Dim sql As String = "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id IN (" & inList & ")"
```

The traditional way is usually faster as LINQ; however, you only note a difference if you have very large enumerations (>100000) or if you make very precise measurements. Choose the approach, which you find easier to use.

Comment: Is this the way to iterate a Dropdownlist with Linq? Better performance than regular loop?